Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 - Client Side
I'm investigating the migration from legacy FCM Apis to HTTP v1.  I understand there are differences in the json payload, however as on Android we receive the RemoteMessage object, can someone confirm that there will be no need for changes on the client side?
Assuming that the Remote Message contains the same map, there shouldn't be any changes required, or have I missed something?
Thank you in advance
